# When to use set -e

Tags: bash, shell

I come across `set -e` a some time ago and I admit I love it. 
Now, after some time I'm back to write some bash scripting.

My question is if there are some best practices when to use `set -e` and when not to use it (.e.g. in small/big scripts etc.) or should I rather use a pattern like `cmd || exit 1` to track errors?

Comment: See also [What does 'set -e' do, and why might it be considered dangerous?](http://serverfault.com/q/143445/204345) on Server Fault. Especially the [Debian bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg473314.html) is quite a gotcha in my opinion.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, you should always use it. People make fun of Visual Basic all the time, saying it's not a real programming language, partly because of its “On Error Resume Next” statement. Yet that is the default in shell! `set -e` should have been the default. The potential for disaster is just too high.

---

In places where it's ok for a command to fail, you can use `|| true` or its shortened form `||:`, e.g.

```
grep Warning build.log ||:
```

---

In fact you should go a step further, and have

```
set -eu
set -o pipefail
```

at the top of every `bash` script.

`-u` makes it an error to reference a non-existent environment variable such as `${HSOTNAME}`, at the cost of requiring some gymnastics with checking `${#}` before you reference `${1}`, `${2}`, and so on.

`pipefail` makes things like `misspeled-command | sed -e 's/^WARNING: //'` raise errors.

Comment: Everybody here has personal preferences regarding the question. Your answer is most close to me, so I accept it.

Answer (score 5):

If your script code checks for errors carefully and properly where necessary, and handles them in an appropriate manner, then you probably don't ever need or want to use `set -e`.

On the other hand if your script is a simple sequential list of commands to be run one after another, and if you want the script to terminate if any one of those fail, then sticking `set -e` at the top would be exactly what you would want to do to keep your script simple and uncluttered.  A perfect example of this would be if you're creating a script to compile a set of sources and you want the compile to stop after the first file with errors is encountered.

More complex scripts can combine these methods since you can use `set +e` to turn its effect back off again and go back to explicit error checking.

Note that although `set -e` is supposed to cause the shell to exit *IFF* any *untested* command fails, it is wise to turn it off again when your code is doing its own error handling as there can easily be weird cases where a command will return a non-zero exit status that you're not expecting, and possibly even such cases that you might not catch in testing, and where sudden fatal termination of your script would leave something in a bad state.  So, don't use `set -e`, or leave it turned on after using it briefly, unless you really know that you want it.

Note also that you can still define an error handler with `trap ERR` to do something on an error condition when `set -e` is in effect, as that will still be run before the shell exits.

Comment: I disagree. I think you should use 'set -e' by default and only remove it if you really need to. The last thing you want is an unhandled error to cause a cascade of more errors or some sort of incorrect behaviour from your script.

Comment: @MikeWeller happy to hear other opinion :)

Comment: 25+ years of experience reading and writing scripts for production use suggests that `set -e` is rarely useful.

Comment: @MikeWeller - I'll have to agree with Greg here.  If you're at risk of ignoring important failures when you write shell scripts, then perhaps you should hire a consultant or contractor to help write them.  Greg, for example.

Comment: Why of course he should pay Greg the $$$ instead of typing `set -e`

Comment: @GregA.Woods can you tell what you mean by _untested_ command fails here and also what could be fatal termination in the script or for a bash command, even in case of fatal termination won't it exit with a error code not equal to 0?

Comment: Bit late in the day, but I couldn't agree more. I am an old ***, who writes a lot of scripts.  Set -e has never been useful.  People saying "best practice" are often simply asserting something they have read on the internet (so it must be true).  Catch your own errors. Properly

Comment: A belated sorry @TapasweniPathak, I missed your question.  An _untested_ command is one where the shell isn't using the exit code itself, e.g. to decide the outcome of a short-circuit list control operator (`&&`, `||`), or in the conditional term of a flow control statement (`if`, `while`).

Answer (score 4):

You **love** it!?

For my self, I prefer in a wide, having in my `.bashrc` a line like this:

```
trap '/usr/games/fortune /usr/share/games/fortunes/bofh-excuses' ERR
```

( on debian: `apt-get install fortunes-bofh-excuses` :-)

But it's only my preference ;-)

**More seriously**

```
lastErr() {
    local RC=$?
    history 1 |
         sed '
  s/^ *[0-9]\+ *\(\(["'\'']\)\([^\2]*\)\2\|\([^"'\'' ]*\)\) */cmd: \"\3\4\", args: \"/;
  s/$/", rc: '"$RC/"
}
trap "lastErr" ERR

Gna
bash: Gna : command not found
cmd: "Gna", args: "", rc: 127

Gna gna
cmd: "Gna", args: "gna", rc: 127

"Gna gna" foo
cmd: "Gna gna", args: "foo", rc: 127
```

Well, from there, you could:

```
trap "lastErr >>/tmp/myerrors" ERR
"Gna gna" foo

cat /tmp/myerrors 
cmd: "Gna gna", args: "foo", rc: 1
```

Or better:

```
lastErr() {
local RC=$?
history 1 |
     sed '
  s/^ *[0-9]\+ *\(\(["'\'']\)\([^\2]*\)\2\|\([^"'\'' ]*\)\) */cmd: \"\3\4\", args: \"/;
  s/$/", rc: '"$RC/
  s/^/$(date +"%a %d %b %T ")/"
}
"Gna gna" foo

cat /tmp/myerrors 
cmd: "Gna gna", args: "foo", rc: 1
Tue 20 Nov 18:29:18 cmd: "Gna gna", args: "foo", rc: 127
```

... You could even add other informations like `$$, $PPID, $PWD` or maybe your..

Comment: Care about using `/tmp`! This could become a security flaw! Maybe using another place like `$HOME/.bash_errors` will be appropriated!

Answer (score 0):

When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons  listed  in  Consequences  of  Shell  Errors  or returns an exit status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list, and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word,  then  the  shell  shall  immediately
exit.

Comment: Thanks, but my question when it's recommended to use it? For example I don't see it's used in init scripts (/etc/init.d/*)

Comment: It would be dangerous to use "set -e" when creating init.d scripts:

Be careful of using set -e in init.d scripts. init.d scripts requires exit statuses when daemons are running or stopped without aborting the init.d script. so whenever you don't care about aborting you program if error happens use set, otherwise no